# Is it safe to OSGi export API containing reference to implementation code?

Tags: java, api, export, osgi

Let's imagine I implement the following:

```
public enum ExportAPIForOSGi {
    ;
    public static SpecialObject newSpecialObject() {
        return new SpecialObjectImplv1();
    }
}

public abstract class SpecialObject {
    public abstract String specialMethod(String s);
}

public class SpecialObjectImplv1 extends SpecialObject {
    @Override
    public String specialMethod(String s) {
        return "33" + s;
    }
}
```

Each class is declared in its own separate file. Only `ExportAPIForOSGi` and `SpecialObject` are to be OSGi exported.

My question: is it safe to export `ExportAPIForOSGi` since it contains an explicit reference to implementation code (i.e., `SpecialObjectImplv1`)? Is the implementation code going to be exposed?

Let's imagine that later, I use `SpecialObjectImplv2` in `ExportAPIForOSGi` instead of v1? Is this going to be an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the package(s) containing ExportAPIForOSGi and SpecialObject since they are your public API. SpecialObjectImplv1 should be in another package which is not exported. You are then free to change the implementation of newSpecialObject to use another impl class since the impl class is not visible in the signature of the public API.

Comment: Ok, so if understand you well, it is only what is declared public and appearing in public signatures that matters, correct? If I am 100% sure implementation code does not appear in whatever is declared public (but may be used inside the class file), then I am safe, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the @ to notify you.

Comment: @JVersty, You should only export the interfaces/API you don't intend to change. This leaves you free to change the implementation. If you change any exported class, you must unload every module which uses that module.